# Error When Unit Testing AngularJS Directive that uses ngInclude w/ QUnit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, qunit

I am currently trying to set up Unit Testing for my Angular directive using QUnit. Everything was going great until I tried to use the ngInclude directive. I am now receiving the following error when compiling my directive in the test:

> Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <-
>   $anchorScroll <- ngIncludeDirective

Simply changing my directive's template from:

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td data-ng-repeat="column in row.columns">{{ column.data }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To:

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td data-ng-repeat="column in row.columns">{{ column.data }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-include="'footerRow.html'" />
</table>
```

Is enough to kick off the error. The simplest form of the Unit Test code is:

```
QUnit.test('Directive renders something', function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myModule']);
    var $compile = this.$injector.get('$compile');
    var $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    // Build up the scope, call $compile, and get the error
    var element = $compile('<div data-my-directive="" />')($scope);
});
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something easy and obvious, but I've been staring too long. Please feel free to prove me right.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help if you put this into a JSFiddle -- you might see what is happening here.

Try changing this:

`<tr data-ng-include="'footerRow.html'" />`

to this:

`<tr data-ng-include src="'footerRow.html'" />`